# Do q-ary lattices have parallelogram kind of structure?

Tags: lattice-crypto

An $m$-dimensional lattice is defined by a basis $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is the set of points $\{Az : z \in \mathbb{Z}^n\}$. A picture of these points would be like a nice parallelogram kind of structure.

In crypto, we use $q$-ary integer lattices defined by basis $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times n}$ and is defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^m : \exists z \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n, x = Az \mod q\}$. I couldn't imagine how these lattices look like. Do these also have the same kind of parallelogram structure? Why do cryptographers use these lattices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the matrix $A$ defines a $q$-ary lattice $L$, but it is not a basis of $L$.

Let $m \ge n$, write $A$ in blocks, as follows: $A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $A_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times n}$ and  $A_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m-n\times n}$. Additionally, let's also write the vectors $x \in L$ as "block" vectors $(x_1 \quad x_2)$.

Now, suppose that $A_1$ is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Then we see that $x \in L \Leftrightarrow x = Az \mod q \Leftrightarrow x_1 = A_1z \mod q \text{ and } x_2 = A_2z \mod q $.

But that means that $A_1^{-1}x_1 = z \mod q$ and $x_2 = A_2(A_1^{-1}x_1) \mod q$.

Therefore, over the integers, there is an $(m-n)$-dimensional vector $u$ such that $x_2 = A_2A_1^{-1}x_1 + qu$.

Thus, it is easy to see that the columns of the following matrix form a basis of $L$:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} I_n & O \\ A_2A_1^{-1} & qI_{m-n} \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}.$$

If we do $B\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ u \end{pmatrix}$ we get exactly $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ A_2A_1^{-1}x_1 + qu \end{pmatrix}$, as expected.

Now, answering your other questions:

> Do these also have the same kind of parallelogram structure?

Yes, all lattices have such structure. The parallelogram in this case is defined by the columns of $B$.

> Why do cryptographers use these lattices?

Those lattices appear naturally in cryptography because of problems like [SIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer_solution_problem) and [LWE](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf).

There is plenty of material about that on the internet, for example, [this tutorial](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/938.pdf) on lattice-based crypto.

Comment: Thank you very much for that tutorial link

Comment: Here's what I understand. When we consider any q-ary lattice with basis $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times n}$, it corresponds to an integer lattice with basis $B$ described above.

Comment: So, q-ary lattices are a small subset of integer lattices.

Comment: It is not correct to say that $A$ is the basis of the $q$-ary lattice. For each $A$, you have a $q$-ary lattice $\Lambda_q(A)$. So, $A$ is defining the lattice, but it is not a basis of it. This lattice is full-rank of dimension $m$, therefore, any basis must have $m$ vectors of dimension $m$.
And yes, it is a sublattice of $\mathbb{Z}^m$. But you just need the definition to see that, since it states that the lattice is composed by $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that $x$ has some property...