# Software package to create a basis of the q-ary lattice $\Lambda_q(A)$

Tags: lattice-crypto

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times n}$ and its respective lattice
$$\Lambda_q(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}^m : \exists z \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n, x = Az \mod q\}$$
The basis for such a lattice is different from $A$ as shown in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72068/87135). I am looking for a software package/library that construct such a basis, so I can then for example run the LLL algorithm on it. Does any such package already exist?

Comment: Both constructing a basis from $A$ and running LLL are easily done in Sage. For example, see [this PDF](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/sage-introduction.pdf#page=22).

Comment: Note that the .pdf @HilderVitorLimaPereira mentions (and Sage overall I believe) uses the notation the convention that lattices are generated by *rows* of a given matrix (the basis $B$), while your definition of $\Lambda_q(A)$ uses the convention that lattices are generated by the *columns* of the matrix (the basis $B^t$). This is an unfortunately easy thing to overlook and get quite confused about. Also, it is worth mentioning that while the basis for $\Lambda_q(A)$ may not be $A$, a *generating set* for the lattice is given by $[A, qI_m]$, where $[A, B]$ denotes horizontal concatenation ...

Comment: Here, I use the convention that lattices are generated by linear combinations of the columns of some matrix, i.e. are written as $L = B\mathbb{Z}^n$ for a basis $B$. To use the row notation you take transposes, which explains why the .pdf stacks the matrices vertically.