# Finding a basis for q-ary lattices

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

For $A\in \mathbb{Z_q}^{n\times m}$, where $m \geq n$, consider the  given two q-ary lattices
\begin{align}
\Lambda_q^{\bot}{(A)} & = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^m: A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}\text{  mod }q\} \\
\Lambda_q{(A)} & = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^m: \mathbf{x} = A^T\mathbf{s} \text{  mod }q \text{ for some } \mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q\}.
\end{align}

Compute a basis for the above two lattices

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: The standard way of computing a basis of $\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$ is by supposing that $A$ contains an invertible block, as it is done [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72064/do-q-ary-lattices-have-parallelogram-kind-of-structure/72068#72068). Then, the basis of $\Lambda_q(A)$ can be obtained by computing computing the [dual basis](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/DualLattice.pdf), since these two lattices are (the scaled) dual of each other.